# Output member email address without javascript encoding

Tags: templates, members, javascript

I'm trying to get a member's email address to autopopulate a form field but if I use {email} then the output is the Javascript encoded "safe" email address. Obviously I dont want this, I just want the email address itself.

How can I turn off the encoding - ideally in just this instance?

This site is running EE 2.4 and I can't update it for the moment. Seems odd that the member email is being encoded. It's not coming from a channel entry so I can't simply turn off the encoding option in channel prefs and I'm not using the {encode} tag.

Comment: Is the `{email}` tag wrapped with any plugin/module tags that could be altering EE's usual parsing behaviour? Depending on the context you might want to try the `{logged_in_email}` variable as that's less likely to be impacted by any other modules you're using.

Comment: It is within another tag but the behaviour is the same when outside the tag pair too. Your suggestion of logged_in_email worked a treat though, if you'd care to add that as an answer I'll accept it so you get the rep. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. The `logged_in_x` vars are always worth a shot if something isn't working as you'd expect it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the context you might want to try the `{logged_in_email}` variable as that's less likely to be impacted by any other modules you're using.

*Reposted as an answer rather than a comment as it seems to have worked.*

Comment: {logged_in_email} worked for me for outputting the raw email address within {exp:member:custom_profile_data}